# How to pick elements from a set and use them in a sum (or product)

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I would like to obtain the sum (or some other reduction) from a set which is the result of a previous operation:

```
NSolve[z^5 == 1, z, Complexes]

{{z -> -0.809017 - 0.587785 I}, {z -> -0.809017 + 0.587785 I}, {z -> 
   0.309017 - 0.951057 I}, {z -> 0.309017 + 0.951057 I}, {z -> 1.}}
```

How do I address these elements individually and how can I form a sum (or product)?

Comment: `sol = NSolve[z^5 == 1, z, Complexes];
{Plus @@ (z /. sol), Times @@ (z /. sol)}`

Comment: Also `Plus@@soln[[All,1,2]]` and `Times@@soln[[All,1,2]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
solVals = Last /@ Flatten[NSolve[z^5 == 1, z, Complexes]]

solVals1 = NSolveValues[z^5 == 1, z, Complexes]

solVals == solVals1
(* True *)

 Plus @@ sol
(* 0.+0.I) 

 Times @@ sol
(1. + 0.I *)
```

For exact sum much better approach is

```
RootSum[#^5 - 1 &, # &]
```

(* 0 *)

Comment: For the product: `Exp@RootSum[#^5 - 1 &, Log]` gives $1$.

Comment: @Acus: Mathematica 12 does not recognize NSolveValues; is it a new feature?

Comment: @Vectorizer   Documentation says it was introduced in 2021, in version 12.3

Comment: @Acus: Thanks. I am using 12.0